# Como fazer uma expressão regular para telefone celular?

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

Como criar uma expressão regular para validar o campo telefone que aceite 
99-99999999 (DDD + 8 números) ou 99-999999999 (DDD + 9 números). E que ao digitar ele adicione o traço **-** automaticamente!

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{2}-([0-9]{8}|[0-9]{9})"
```

Como proceder?

Comment: Recomendo fortemente que você remova traços ou quaisquer caracteres não numéricos. Ou seja, valide apenas os números. Máscaras são apenas para melhorar a apresentação e elas podem ser aplicadas por meios melhores e distintos. Até mesmo porque para persistir no BD as boas praticas nos orientam usar apenas os números. Isto também facilita a manutenção do seu regex.

Comment: Este regex valida todos os celulares válidos brasileiros com todos os códigos de área válidos (DDD) conforme esta fonte https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discagem_direta_%C3%A0_dist%C3%A2ncia , desde que contenha apenas números. ```^(1[1-9]|2[12478]|3([1-5]|[7-8])|4[1-9]|5(1|[3-5])|6[1-9]|7[134579]|8[1-9]|9[1-9])9[0-9]{8}$``` Caso queira testar utilize este site https://regex101.com/ .

Comment: Sobre o ultimo comentário; tem esse regex aqui que está mais suscinto e facil de manter ```^(1[1-9]|[4689][0-9]|2[12478]|3([1-5]|[7-8])|5([13-5])|7[193-7])9[0-9]{8}$```. 

Answer (score 95):

Hoje em dia, todos os telefones celulares no Brasil têm nove dígitos e iniciam com o dígito 9 e todos os telefones fixos têm 8 dígitos e nunca iniciam com o dígito 9. Eu pessoalmente preferiria formatar o telefone como `(xx) xxxxx-xxxx`. Assim sendo, a melhor expressão regular para isso seria essa:

```
^\([1-9]{2}\) (?:[2-8]|9[0-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

A explicação completa dela é:

- `^` - Início da string.
- `\(` - Um abre parênteses.
- `[1-9]{2}` - Dois dígitos de 1 a 9. Não existem códigos de DDD com o dígito 0.
- `\)` - Um fecha parênteses.
- - Um espaço em branco.
- `(?:[2-8]|9[0-9])` - O início do número. Representa uma escolha entre um dígito de 2 a 8 (a parte do `[2-8]`) e de um 9 seguido de um dígito de 0 a 9 (a parte do `9[0-9]`). O `|` separa as opções a serem escolhidas. O `(?: ... )` agrupa tais escolhas. Telefones fixos começam com dígitos de 2 a 8. Telefones celulares começam com 9 e têm um segundo dígito de 0 a 9. O primeiro dígito nunca será 0 ou 1.
- `[0-9]{3}` - Os demais três dígitos da primeira metade do número do telefone, perfazendo um total de 4 ou 5 dígitos na primeira metade.
- `\-` - Um hífen.
- `[0-9]{4}` - A segunda metade do número do telefone.
- `$` - Final da string.

Se você quiser deixar os parênteses, o espaço em branco e hífen opcionais, então você pode colocar um `?` após cada um desses símbolos, resultando nesta expressão regular:

```
^\(?[1-9]{2}\)? ?(?:[2-8]|9[0-9])[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{4}$
```

---

Se você quiser, também é possível também filtrar os DDDs que existem. Eis uma imagem que mostra os códigos de área existentes no momento de acordo com a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discagem_direta_a_dist%C3%A2ncia):

[image: Mapa do Brasil com as divisões por DDD]

Olhando-se então para esse mapa, a subexpressão que filtraria os DDDs válidos seria a seguinte:

```
(?:[14689][1-9]|2[12478]|3[1234578]|5[1345]|7[134579])
```

Como já explicado, o `(?: ... )` é para agrupar. As opções (separadas por `|`) seriam grupos de dois dígitos, que seria uma das seguintes opções: `2[12478]` para Rio de Janeiro e Espírito Santo, `3[1234578]` para Minas Gerais, `5[1345]` para Rio Grande do Sul, `7[134579]` para Bahia e Sergipe e `[14689][1-9]` para o restante do Brasil.

E a expressão regular completa seria a seguinte (com os parênteses, espaços e hífens obrigatórios):

```
^\((?:[14689][1-9]|2[12478]|3[1234578]|5[1345]|7[134579])\) (?:[2-8]|9[0-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

E com eles não obrigatórios:

```
^\(?(?:[14689][1-9]|2[12478]|3[1234578]|5[1345]|7[134579])\)? ?(?:[2-8]|9[0-9])[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{4}$
```

---

<sup><sub>NOTA: Esta resposta foi escrita originalmente em 2015, quando haviam celulares de 8 ou 9 dígitos, dependendo do DDD. Desde então, ela foi atualizada para o formato mais novo em vigor, que sempre tem 9 dígitos. Se quiser mais detalhes sobre como esta resposta foi editada, confira o [histórico de edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/46676/revisions). Números celulares também não podiam começar com 90, porque esse é o prefixo para ligações a cobrar, mas isso também mudou.</sub></sup>

Comment: o que quer dizer este escapar `\ ` antes do espaço? Aqui `...^\([1-9]{2}\)\ [2-9]...` Não acho que seja necessário escapar um espaço :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Realmente. Não lembro porque eu havia colocado a barra antes, vez que já se passaram alguns meses. Acho que eu devo ter me complicado com alguma coisa na hora de construir a regex.

Comment: Victor é normal, eu faço isto direto, o JorgeB. vive seguindo meus erros de ortografia :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa, você merece um prêmio pela belíssima explicação. Melhor que muito tutorial de regex blogs a fora...

Comment: Eu uso um `\s` para escapara o espaço. Isso porque eu estou usando uma mascara no campo e tenho certeza que sempre vai vir esse espaço.

Comment: @VictorStafusa obrigado!

Comment: caraio menó, q aula de regex!

Answer (score 9):

Minha solução pode não ser a mais efetiva, mas como não vi muitas soluções comentando sobre alguns pontos resolvi escrever a minha.

Eu criei uma expressão regular que identifica se uma string é um telefone, levando em conta os seguintes casos:

> - Telefones 0800
> - Números de operadoras e serviços como 10315 e 190
> - Telefones representados com ou sem parênteses
> - Aceita operadora representada como 0xx11
> - Telefones com ou sem os separadores [ .-]
> - Ignora telefones começados com 0 se não tiver DDD (ex: 0999-9999 não é aceito, mas 0xx11 9123-1234 é)

Ficou um pouco grande e difícil de ler humanamente, mas atende meus projetos:

```
/^1\d\d(\d\d)?$|^0800 ?\d{3} ?\d{4}$|^(\(0?([1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z])?[1-9]\d\) ?|0?([1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z])?[1-9]\d[ .-]?)?(9|9[ .-])?[2-9]\d{3}[ .-]?\d{4}$/gm
```

Você pode ver a expressão em uso [neste link](http://regexr.com/3dkvr).

Depois de validar se a expressão é um telefone, você pode formatar do jeito que achar melhor manipulando a string.

Segue um exemplo em Java (onde PHONE_MATCH é a expressão regular):

```
public String phone(String phoneString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (!phoneString.matches(PHONE_MATCH)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid phone format");
    }

    String str = phoneString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

    if (str.charAt(0) == '0') {
        if (str.charAt(1) == '0') {
            str = str.substring(2);
        } else {
            str = str.substring(1);
        }
    }

    switch (str.length()) {
        case 8:
            return applyMask(str, "AAAA-AAAA", 'A');
        case 9:
            return applyMask(str, "AAAAA-AAAA", 'A');
        case 10:
            return applyMask(str, "(AA) AAAA-AAAA", 'A');
        case 11:
            return applyMask(str, "(AA) AAAAA-AAAA", 'A');
        default:
            return str;
    }
}
```

Método applyMask:

```
public String applyMask(String str, String mask, char specialChar) {

    // Conta quantos caracteres especiais existem na máscara
    int maskChCount = mask.length() - mask.replaceAll("[^" + specialChar + "]", "").length();

    // Conta apenas os números
    int strChCount = str.length() - str.replaceAll("\\d", "").length();

    // Exceção caso a string nao tenha números suficientes para competar a máscara
    if (strChCount < maskChCount) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of chars in the string should not be smaller than the " +
                "number of special chars in the mask");
    }

    char[] maskChars = mask.toCharArray();
    char[] strChars = str.toCharArray();

    // Itera por todos os elementos da máscara
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < maskChars.length && j < strChars.length; i++) {
        char ch = maskChars[i];
        char sh = strChars[j];

        if (ch == specialChar) {
            // Se achou o caractere especial, buscar o próximo elemento aceito da String e 
            // substituí-lo no local do caractere especial
            while (!Character.toString(sh).matches("\\d")) {
                j++;
                sh = strChars[j];
            }
            maskChars[i] = sh;
            j++;
        }
    }

    return new String(maskChars);
}
```

Acredito que tenha várias formas de otimizar este código, qualquer sugestão é bem vinda.

Comment: Não usei sua resposta, mas muito obrigado pelo site que você fez seu exemplo. http://regexr.com

Comment: Usa expressão regular de forma incompleta pra depois jogar um monte de código random pra tentar consertar o que ficou incompleto com a expressão regular. Isso sem falar que a pergunta era genérica ou talvez para vb.net (veja as tags) e a resposta dada é em Java. E ao tentar aceitar qualquer telefone em qualquer formato, mesmo aqueles que provavelmente ninguém quer aceitar, acaba criando um monstrinho que é difícil de se entender como funciona. Além disso, esta resposta segue a lógica do "pra que simplificar se posso complicar?".

Answer (score 5):

Eu uso essa

```
@"^\(?\d{2}\)?[\s-]?[\s9]?\d{4}-?\d{4}$"
```

se você coloca 9 dígitos ela te obrigado que o primeiro digito seja 9.

Eu pegaria um pouco de cada exemplo pra montar a ideal.

Comment: Gabriel Santos Reis, sua máscara é perfeita cara. Parabéns!

Answer (score 3):

Gente, com a ajuda de vocês eu criei uma string que achei ideal para mim. Simples e direta. No WHMCS use para iniciar e fechar /. Não usarei no exemplo para seguir o exemplo de vocês. Vamos lá. A expressão fica assim:

```
^\([1-9]{2}\) [9]{0,1}[6-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

Explicação:

- `^` = Início da string.
- `\(` = Um abre parênteses.
- `[1-9]{2}` = Dois dígitos de 1 a 9. Não existem códigos de DDD com o dígito 0.
- `\)` = Um fecha parênteses.
- = Um espaço em branco.
- `[9]{0,1}` = O primeiro dígito é 9, mais ele pode ou não existir daí o "0" ou "1" dentro da {0,1}.
- `[6-9]{1}` = o segundo dígito pode ser de 6 à 9.
- `[0-9]{3}` = Os três outros dígitos são de 0 à 9
- `\-` = Um hífen.
- `[0-9]{4}` = A segunda metade do número do telefone.
- `$` = Final da string.

Lembrando amigos que no WHMCS se deve iniciar e fechar com /. Até o final de 2016 ou mais preciso em 06 de novembro de 2016 todo o Brasil terá o 9 no início dos celulares.

Comment: Meu celular começa com 95. A sua regra de "*o segundo dígito pode ser de 6 à 9*" barraria o meu celular.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é so mudar para `^\([1-9]{2}\) [9]{0,1}[5-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
`
de onde você é e que operadora é a sua para começar com 95?

Comment: @LeoCavalcante Sou de São Paulo e uso a TIM, mas com a portabilidade, a operadora pouco importa. O DDD 11 é o que tem o maior número de linhas registradas. Pelo que me lembro, de acordo com a Anatel, a regra é que todos os números de telefones de 9 dígitos começando com 9 são celulares, e começam a contar do número 99999-9999 de trás-para-frente até o 91000-0000, que é quando se esgotaria a quantidade de linhas disponíveis no DDD. E se não me engano, já temos os primeiros números começando com 94 no DDD 11. Tenho uma outra resposta aqui nesta pergunta que evita essas limitações.

Comment: @LeoCavalcante Na verdade, já tenho um número na minha lista de contatos começando com 93 no DDD 11.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\([1-9]{2}\) 9[7-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

- `[1-9]{2}` = Dois dígitos de 1 a 9. Não existem DDD com o dígito 0.
- `9` = Todos os celulares a partir de 2016 começam por 9
- `[7-9]{1}` = Na numeração antiga os celulares começavam com 7, 8 ou 9
- `[0-9]{3}` = Os três outros dígitos podem ser de 0 à 9
- `[0-9]{4}` = Os quatro depois do hífen podem ser de 0 à 9

Comment: Meu celular começa com 95. Ele é rejeitado pela sua regex.

Comment: Graças ao nono dígito, agora podemos ter celulares que começam com 96, 95, 94, etc. Então usar `[7-9]` rejeita números válidos, como bem apontou o @VictorStafusa. Outro detalhe é que `{1}` é desnecessário, pois `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)`