# Expressão regular para Telefones somente com números e DDD C#

Tags: c#, regex

Gostaria de uma ajuda para criar uma expressão regular em C# que valide número de telefones com DDD mas sem pontos e traços, somente números. Seria com o formato XX12345678 e XX 123456789.

Comment: Que tal: `.. ......(.(.(.)?)?)?` Espaço só par facilitar a leitura, não real. E no lugar de `.` você pode colocar `[0-9]`

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha nesse link abaixo que tem uma resposta super explicadinha sobre essa sua questão. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46672/como-fazer-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular-para-telefone-celular

Answer (score 4):

Sem a necessidade real de fazer validação de DDD, apenas dígitos fica :

```
\d{10,11}
```

```js
var list = [
  '5112345678',
  '61123456789',
  '1112345678',
  '21123456789',
];

for(var i in list){
  console.log(list[i], /\d{10,11}/.test(list[i]));
}
```

Comment: Tem ligares em que ainda se utiliza 7 dígitos para telefone, em alguns interiores perdidos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado basta fazer o calculo 7 dígitos (min) + 2 DDD = 9 então inicia em 9 e o outro 9 dígitos (max) +2 DDD = 11, assim o intervalo fica de `{9,11}`