# Máscara para campo telefone

Tags: php, javascript

Como é possível fazer uma máscara em um input de telefone somente para aceitar números e já entrar na formatação (xx) xxxxx-xxxx

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Esta sua pergunta pode ser respondida visualizando esta outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282311/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-campo-tipo-telefone?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Aprendi neste site mesmo, utilizar desta ocorrência, da seguinte maneira:

```js
$("#telefone, #celular").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
```

```html
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
 
 <label>Telefone</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" id="telefone" name="telefone" ><br>
<label>Celular</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Celular" id="celular" name="celular" ><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando jQuery, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$('#id_do_campo').mask('(99) 99999-9999');
```

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo abaixo contempla celular com 9 dígitos (Celular São Paulo)

```
var options = {
    onKeyPress: function (phone, e, field, options) {
        var masks = ['(00) 0000-00000', '(00) 00000-0000'];
        var mask = (phone.length > 14) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
        $('#celular').mask(mask, options);
    }
};

$('#celular').mask('(00) 0000-00000', options);
```