# Validação com expressão regular considera inválido mesmo quando encontra um match

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, validação

Gostaria de saber o que está de errado nesse código. Todos os valores válidos que insiro no nome, email e telefone acusam como inválido, mesmo estando no formato solicitado pela regex.

```
import re

class Contato: 

def __init__(self):
    self.__nome = ''
    self.__email = ''
    self.__telefone = ''

def __validaEmail(self, email):
    result = re.match('(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)', str(email))
    if result == None:
        return False

def __validaTelefone(self, telefone):
    result = re.match('(d{2}) d{4,5}-d{4}', str(telefone))
    if result == None:
        return False

def inicializaContato(self, nome, email, telefone):
    if self.__validaTelefone(telefone) and self.__validaNome(nome) and self.__validaEmail(email):
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__email = email
        self.telefone = telefone

def getNome(self):
    return self.__nome
def getEmail(self):
    return self.__email
def getTelefone(self):
    return self.__telefone

def setNome(self, nome):
    str(nome).strip()
    if str(nome).isalpha():
        self.__nome = nome
    else:
        print('\033[1;31m','NOME INVALIDO!','\033[m')

def setEmail(self, email):
    if self.__validaEmail(email):
        self.__email = email
    else:
        print('\033[1;31m','EMAIL INVALIDO!','\033[m')

def setTelefone(self, telefone):
    if self.__validaTelefone(telefone):
        self.__telefone = telefone
    else:
        print('\033[1;31m','TELEFONE INVALIDO!','\033[m')
```

Comment: E quais são os valores aparentemente válidos que você inseriu e acusou como inválidos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos analisar o método que valida email:

```
def __validaEmail(self, email):
    result = re.match('(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)', str(email))
    if result == None:
        return False
```

Quando `result` for `None`, você retorna `False`, mas quando ele não for `None` (ou seja, quando o email for válido), você não retorna nada. E com isso o "retorno" da função acaba sendo `None`. Exemplo:

```
def f(x):
    if x == 1:
        return True

print(f(2)) # None
```

Se eu passar 2, a função não entra no `if` e não retorna nada, por isso o código acima imprime `None`.

E como `None` é interpretado como falso, `if self.__validaEmail(email)` estará testando o mesmo que `if None`, o que é sempre falso.

Sendo assim, você deve alterar a validação para sempre retornar o resultado do *match*:

```
def __validaEmail(self, email):
    return re.match(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)', str(email))

def __validaTelefone(self, telefone):
    return re.match(r'(d{2}) d{4,5}-d{4}', str(telefone))
```

Se a regex encontrar um *match*, ela retorna o resultado correspondente, e ao testá-lo no `if`, ele será considerado verdadeiro (objetos por padrão [são avaliados como verdadeiro](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)).

Mas ainda há um problema na regex do telefone. Você usou `d{2}`, que significa "duas ocorrências da letra `d`". Se você quis dizer "dois dígitos", na verdade deve usar o [atalho `\d`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-28).

Outro detalhe é que os parênteses possuem significado especial em regex (servem para formar [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)). Se você quer que o telefone tenha parênteses de fato, deve escapá-los com `\`, assim eles perdem seu significado especial e passam a ser interpretados como os caracteres `(` e `)`.

Então os métodos de validação ficam assim:

```
def __validaEmail(self, email):
    return re.match(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)', str(email))

def __validaTelefone(self, telefone):
    return re.match(r'\(\d{2}\) \d{4,5}-\d{4}', str(telefone))
```

Testando:

```
c = Contato()
c.setEmail('teste@teste.com')
print(c.getEmail())
c.setTelefone('(11) 92812-1221')
print(c.getTelefone())
```

Saída:

> teste@teste.com
>   (11) 92812-1221

---

#### Sobre as regex

As regex usadas acima são relativamente simples, mas elas podem ser melhoradas, se for o caso.

A do telefone, por exemplo, aceita valores como `(00) 00000-0000`. Se isso é aceitável para os seus testes, tudo bem, mas você pode melhorar e usar as opções [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46672/112052).

Já a regex do email aceita valores como `_.+@-.-`. Claro que dá para melhorar, e eu comento mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) (este último link tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última regex).

Mas basicamente, quanto mais simples a regex, mais casos "estranhos" ela vai considerar válidos, porém quanto mais precisa, mais complexa ela vai ficando. Escolha o que for melhor para o seu caso, sempre lembrando de balancear a praticidade (se é fácil de entender e manter) e a precisão (ela valida o que eu quero, e também não valida o que eu não quero).

---

#### Sobre o nome

O método [`isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha) não aceita espaços (e *acredito* que você deve ter testado com nomes que tem espaços). Mas como não foi dito quais valores você usou para testar, podemos especular um pouco.

Podemos usar algo simples como `\w+(?: \w+)+`. O `\w` é um atalho para "letras, números ou o caractere `_`". Esta regex aceita vários `\w`, seguido de (várias ocorrências de "espaço seguido de vários `\w`"). Ou seja, nomes contendo vários sobrenomes, todos separados por espaço.

É claro que por ser muito simples, esta regex aceita coisas como `123 a b_`. E aqui é a mesma história dos emails e telefones: quanto mais precisa a regex, mais complicada ela vai ficando.

Podemos eliminar os números e o `_` e ficar somente com as letras usando `[^\W\d_]`:

- `\W` é "tudo que não for `\w`"
- `\d` é qualquer dígito numérico
- `_` é o próprio caractere `_`

O `[^` serve para negar tudo isso. Ou seja, o resultado é o mesmo que "`\w` sem os números e o `_`", sobrando somente as letras. Fiz isso porque no Python 3 o `\w` considera todas as letras definidas no Unicode, o que inclui caracteres acentuados e outros alfabetos (como o japonês, árabe, cirílico, etc). Então ficaria assim:

```
def setNome(self, nome):
    if re.match(r'^[^\W\d_]+(?: [^\W\d_]+)+$', str(nome).strip()):
        self.__nome = nome
    else:
        print('\033[1;31m', 'NOME INVALIDO!', '\033[m')
```

Mas se quiser se limitar ao alfabeto latino e caracteres acentuados, pode usar algo como `[a-zçáéíóúãõâêô....]` (inclua todos os caracteres que quiser entre os colchetes). E para não ter que repetir as letras maiúsculas, use a flag [`IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE):

```
if re.match(r'^[a-zçáéíóúãõâêô]+(?: [a-zçáéíóúãõâêô]+)+$', str(nome).strip(), flags = re.IGNORECASE):
```

Essa regex ainda vai recusar nomes que contém apóstrofo (como "D'aquino", por exemplo), mas creio cabe a você decidir o quanto quer "complicar" a regex e o quão precisa quer que ela seja.

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado pela resposta, explicacao e referencias. Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar essas regex:

```py
def __validaEmail(self, email):
    result = re.match(r'''(
            [a-zA-Z0-9,_%+-]+   # username
            @                   # @ simbol
            [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+      # domain name
            (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}){1,2} # dot-something
            )''', str(email), re.VERBOSE)
    if result == None:
        return False

def __validaTelefone(self, telefone):
    result = re.match(r'''(
            (\d{2}|\(\d{2})\)?  # area code
            (\s|-|\.)?          # separator
            (\d{4})             # first 3 digits
            (\s|-|\.)           # separator
            (\d{4})             # last 4 digits
            (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))? # extention
            )''', str(telefone), re.VERBOSE)
    if result == None:
        return False
```

Comment: Para poder usar uma regex em várias linhas e com comentários, tem que passar a flag [`VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE). Mas o principal problema nem é a regex em si, e sim o fato da função não retornar nada quando `result` não for `None`

Comment: @hkotsubo, entendi. Bom, acho que a resposta de cima vai te ajudar, boa sorte!